# CSS3: Reset alternate table row coloring after a certain class of tr

Tags: css

Here's my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/cnLDF/

I want every `.content` row after each `.heading` row to start with gray, in this case, "content 5".

How do I do it by modifying the CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `adjacent sibling selector` (i used red color for demo purposes):

```
table tr.heading + tr.content {
    background: #f00;
}
```

But note that the `nth-child(even)` will win, then you will colour only the first `.content`, preceeded by an `.header`, that is `odd` (and not `even`).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cnLDF/1/

---

EDIT:

I've tried a bit, and I don't think it's possible with pure CSS (but i'll be happy to be proven wrong): pseudo-elements will always refer to all `tr` elements in the table (with `odd` and `even`), and the last declaration will override the previous... the only way with CSS only imho is to create a static declaration for every case with `adjacent selector` after every heading, that is doable only if you have a small, known, fixed number of content for every heading (let's say 5, or 10...), like this:

```
table tr.heading + tr.content > td {/* stuff */ }  
table tr.heading + tr.content + tr.content > td {/* stuff */ }  
table tr.heading + tr.content + tr.content + tr.content > td {/* stuff */ }  
/* and so on... */
```

If instead you could handle the input, you could easily calculate the output serverside, applying `"odd"` and `"even"` `classes` to `tr`s, and coloring them accordingly.

Comment: Then you are actually asking something else: "how to reset the odd-even state after every header element". I will update the answer accordingly

Comment: For a moment I thought that may be using counters and reseting the counter at the heading could work. But I don't think this is really posible, too.